# Can an Approval Process be created solely via Flow Builder bypassing the Approval Process all together?

Tags: administration, automation, app-development

Can an Approval Process be created solely via Flow Builder bypassing the Approval Process all together?? I have a requirement of sending an approval to specific people and having them interact with a field selecting yes or no during the approval process...the problem is I don't believe this can be accomplished through SF's Approval Process because it locks the record automatically when you submit for approval...

I started looking into Flow Orchestrator which seems to be an awesome tool because THAT from the looks of it is able to bypass the Approval Process all together but my dreams were shattered fairly quickly when I found out it has a limitation of 600 runs per year where you have to pay $1 for any additional run after the 600 runs out which is ridiculous. So, it's 3am where I'm located, I'm on my 2nd red bull and my last honey bun and I'm completely exhausted trying to find a solution, so I turn to you with a glimmer of hope in my eyes that the SF community can shine some light on this.

Is there a way to bypass the approval process all together and use Flow to create a functional multi-step approval process with IF (logic) this is selected in a field THEN take an action, or send for approval to X???

Comment: Depends on how much you want to mimic an SFDC Approval process (locking, unlocking, delegated approvers, point-and-click configuration). But one could obviously send emails with links to records and have the approver update a field that then triggers a new flow that initiates the next step